# User IP Address , Using Proxy or Not , Some Help

Tags: c#, asp.net, proxy, ip-address

please see the below codes :

```
        private string GetUserIPAddress()
        {
            string User_IPAddress = string.Empty;
            string User_IPAddressRange = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(User_IPAddressRange))//without Proxy detection
            {
                User_IPAddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
                //or
                //Client_IPAddress = Request.UserHostAddress;
                //or
                User_IPAddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"];
            }
            else////with Proxy detection
            {
                string[] splitter = { "," };
                string[] IP_Array = User_IPAddressRange.Split(splitter,
                                                              System.StringSplitOptions.None);

                int LatestItem = IP_Array.Length - 1;
                User_IPAddress = IP_Array[LatestItem - 1];
                //User_IPAddress = IP_Array[0];
            }
            return User_IPAddress;
        }
```

**EDIT**-> I replaced my questions from inside codes to the below area!

In the case of : 
1-

`User_IPAddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];`
**and**
`Client_IPAddress = Request.UserHostAddress;`
**and**
`User_IPAddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"];`
is the lower or middle line an alternate for the other lines?
woulld you please give us some explain about these lines?

2-
 `User_IPAddress = IP_Array[LatestItem - 1];`
**and**
`User_IPAddress = IP_Array[0];`

which line should i use ?

thanks in advance

> i created another thread (as comment said) with correct format here :
>   [User IP Address , Using Proxy or Not , Some Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681024/user-ip-address-using-proxy-or-not-some-help)