# User IP Address , Using Proxy or Not

Tags: c#, asp.net, proxy, ip-address

Please see the below codes :

```
    private string GetUserIPAddress()
    {
        string User_IPAddress = string.Empty;
        string User_IPAddressRange = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(User_IPAddressRange))//without Proxy detection
        {
            User_IPAddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
            //or
            //Client_IPAddress = Request.UserHostAddress;
            //or
            //User_IPAddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"];
        }
        else////with Proxy detection
        {
            string[] splitter = { "," };
            string[] IP_Array = User_IPAddressRange.Split(splitter,
                                                          System.StringSplitOptions.None);

            int LatestItem = IP_Array.Length - 1;
            User_IPAddress = IP_Array[LatestItem - 1];
            //User_IPAddress = IP_Array[0];
        }
        return User_IPAddress;
    }
```

In the case of : 
1-

`User_IPAddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];`
**and**
`Client_IPAddress = Request.UserHostAddress;`
**and**
`User_IPAddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"];`
is the lower or middle line an alternate for the other lines?
Would you please give us some explain about these lines?
What are the differences ?

2-
 `User_IPAddress = IP_Array[LatestItem - 1];`
**and**
`User_IPAddress = IP_Array[0];`

Which line should I use?
Would you please give explain about these lines?

Comment: Merged questions, please do not delete this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Don't know the class but chances are Request.UserHostAddress is an alias for Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]. Also REMOTE_HOST would be the hostname but in most cases will just be the ipaddress.

Format of X-Forwarded-For is client1, proxy1, proxy2. So you want the second one. User_IPAddress = IP_Array[0];

Just remember "[Since it is easy to forge an X-Forwarded-For field the given information should be used with care.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For)"